# Difference between the two similar senses of about as a preposition

Tags: differences, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/about) defines the preposition **about** in sense 2 and 3 that are quite similar; their similarity disabled me contradict between such senses.

> Sense 2. [British] Used to indicate movement within a particular area.
>
> - ‘she looked **about the** room.’
>
> Sense 3. [British] Used to express location in a particular place.
>
> - ‘rugs were strewn **about the** hall’.

Though saying ‘rugs were strewn **about the** hall’ is passive but has **about the** phrase similar to that of sense 2 that says ‘she looked **about the** room’, which is not passive. I imagine here that the distinction is the passivity of the sense 3, but I am not sure about that . . . and need some rhymes and the reasons behind saying '...about the room' and '...about the hall' in a similar way. **So, I explicitly ask here that how to capture the meaning of such similar sentences as location or movement?**

I wrote one sentence myself which I could not decide wether it's about location or movement?

> - She walked **about the** park.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I have removed that adverbial sense now, and replaced it with other prepositional sense.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal  sorry by in “gazed about” about is an adverb. It is not clear what your problem is here.

Comment: @user070221, okay saying 'gazed about' is an adverbial phrase than why OED put the example ‘she **looked about** the
room’ within the sense of preposition? Given that **gaze and look** are synonymous to each other.

Comment: @JasonBassford  - well the AHD disagrees https://www.thefreedictionary.com/be+about

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal - so your question is: when used after a verb of perception, is “about”  a preposition or an adverb? Correct?

Comment: Okay, the distinction that Oxford is making is that it's a preposition when a *particular* area is mentioned. Or, in other words, when it's followed by a noun. In **men were floundering about**, it's an adverb. But in **men were floundering about** ***the room*** it's a preposition. Expand the preposition sense 2 to see more examples.

Comment: @JasonBassford are you sure what you are talking about? What’s the difference if you mention the space?

Comment: @user070221 Yes. Compare all of the examples under preposition sense 2 with all of the examples under adverb sense 1.

Comment: @user070221, the question is **still** about **the difference between the two similar prepositional senses.** In case of using about as an adverb, it's totally different than using it as preposition. Saying ‘men were floundering **about**’ is adverb, but saying "they gazed about the house" is a preposition. Meanwhile here the preposition about needs a noun followed by it, and as adverb, not.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal Yes. Based on this, your final sentence is an example of prepositional sense 2: movement.

Comment: @JasonBassford - yes, but what’s the difference?

Comment: @user070221 It's exactly what I said in my comment. Preposition: *They X about Y.* Adverb: *They X about.* The preposition is relative to something else; the adverb is simply the behaviour itself.

Comment: @JasonBassford  - this is a very fine point. Not sure. I’ll check with reliable grammars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oxford Dictionaries, preposition sense 2 of **[about](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/about)** provides these examples:

> ‘she looked about the room’
>   ‘They strolled about the gardens, enjoying the beautiful day.’
>   'I should like to walk about my city again without being subjected to foul-mouthed racist abuse.’
>   ‘He paused, looked about himself for a moment, and sighed.’
>   ‘I paused, gazing about the room, watching carefully for any sign of movement.’
>   ‘While some men can wander about a hardware store for an hour, I can kill 60 minutes or more in a kitchen supply place.’

In all of these examples, it's a person or persons performing a movement-related activity. Either they move or some part of them moves.

This is a **movement** sense.

---

This is in contrast to preposition sense 3 of [**about**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/about):

> ‘rugs were strewn about the hall’
>   ‘he produced a knife from somewhere about his person’
>   ‘Residents near the play area are being disturbed by noise, and beer cans have been left about the area.'

Here, what's being referenced are objects—and none of them are actually in motion. The objects are stationary.

This is a **location** sense.

---

In light of this, consider your final sentence:

> They gazed about the house.

Here, there are people and some part of them (their eyes) are moving about the house. So, this is covered by preposition 2 and is a **movement** sense.

Comment: This is a very personal interpretation of grammar.

Comment: @user070221 It's what Oxford Dictionaries says in its definition of the word—which was the scope of the question.

Answer (score -1):

It refers to different usages of the term [about](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/about), in the first case as a proposition, in the second case as an adverb:

***About***  - preposition - (no order );

(mainly uk, us usually around)

> positioned around a place, often without a clear purpose or order:
>
> - *Their belongings were flung about the room.*

***About*** -  adverb (all directions))

(mainly uk, us usually around)

> in many different directions:
>
> - *They heard someone moving about outside.
>   I've been running about all morning trying to find you.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: The OP hasn't asked about the distinction of about as as a preposition as well as adverb. In fact, he asked the difference between the two similar prepositional senses, lying within the scope of preposition only.